# What is 'Diamond' Open Access?

Tags: terminology, open-access

I have heard of 'green' (self-archiving in a repository) and 'gold' open access (immediate open access in a journal), but what is 'diamond' open access? How does this differ from green or gold open access?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Diamond open access is like gold, in that the article is immediately open access in the journal, and nobody has to pay to read it.  However, in gold open access, the author (or their institution or funding agency) normally has to pay a publication fee to get the article published.  In diamond open access, they don't have to pay, so the process is completely free of charges to both authors and readers.

See http://www.jasonmkelly.com/2013/01/27/green-gold-and-diamond-a-short-primer-on-open-access/

Comment: You have warmed this librarian's heart with this correct answer. :)

Comment: A bit off topic: How, then, does the journal pay its expenses?

Comment: Some through in-kind support and donated labor. Some (see e.g. the Open Library for the Humanities) through pass-the-hat support from libraries and relevant university departments. Some grants. Some advertising. Some a mix of the above strategies. There's lots of ways.

Comment: You could also phrase it this way: Diamond is like green, but with peer review.

Comment: Diamond is gold, but the author (or their institute etc) pays 0.

Comment: See also this article by Bob Rosebrugh on "Experience with a 
Free Electronic 
Journal::Theory and 
Applications of Categories",  a diamond open access journal: Notices of the AMS, January, 2013. : http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/noti930 ."The word “free” in the title intentionally has two 
meanings: free of cost and in a state of liberty. The 
thesis  of  this  note  is  that  mathematics  journals 
should be free and that this can be achieved much 
more easily than might be supposed. "

Comment: Diamond open accesses are definitely the correct way to do journals. You could argue that there is some cost for editing the journal, but this is essentially peanuts in comparison with the price that what the journal actually costs if you take into account the work of the editors / referees / authors (and which are not paid usually). So if the community already pays 95% (or more) of the journal via this, why not paying the remaining part and hosting simply the journals?

Answer (score 4):

I'll add a Venn diagram defining the different types of access:

[image]

Source: [Jamie-farquharson](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=User:Jamie-farquharson&action=edit&redlink=1) - https://doi.org/10.6084/m9.figshare.21598179 [CC BY 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0). [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Open_Access_colours_Venn.svg#/media/File:Open_Access_colours_Venn.svg).

Answer (score -3):

A diamond open access journal can be paid for through the Society's membership fees, which include access to the Journal. If journal access is free anyway, you may ask why would people pay membership fees? Because they believe in the mission of the Society, want to support the open access journal, get a discount on annual meetings, and generally support that society and journal.